# Can vectorization be applied to a function Z= f(X,Y) defined by two or more functions

Tags: python, numpy

I am using np.meshgrid() to plot an scalar function: Z= f(X,Y).

I have no problems when f(X,Y) is defined by a single equation. However, when f(X,Y) is split in two or more equations, such as:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, sparse = True, indexing = 'ij')
Z = f1(X,Y), y1 < y <= y2
Z = f2(X,Y), y > y2
```

I have no idea how to extract the value of 'Y' from the meshgrid array in order to check it against y1 and y2 in the conditional statement. I have tried several ways, like the one below, to no avail:

```
row1, col1 = np.where(Y == y1)
row2, col2 = np.where(Y == y2)
if( Y > Y[row1][0] and Y <= Y[row2][0] ):
    Z = f1(X, Y)
elif ( Y > Y[row2][0] ):
    Z = f2(X, Y)
```

When I use arrays for the calculations of Z, the execution is really slow, at least 10 to 20 times slower, depending on the grid size, when compared with vectorization.
Is it possible to apply vectorization in this case? how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` in general.

```
z = np.where(Y <= y2, f1(X, Y), f2(X, Y))
```

If you have a null case (as it seems with `Y < y1`) you may need to initialize with `np.zeros_like`

```
Z = np.zeros_like(Y)  # same shape and dtype as `Y`
np.where(y1 < Y <= y2, f1(X, Y), out = Z)
np.where(y< y2, f2(X,Y), out = Z)
```

Be aware that if one of your functions raises an error outside its range, you will get errors since `np.where` calculates the function over the entire `X, Y` range.  In that case you'll want to try @Stef 's method

Answer (score 1):

If the split is for a given constant x or y value, as in your example, you could compute the function for both regions (y < y1 and y >= y1) and then stack the result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.1)
y1 = np.arange(-5, 2, 0.1)
y2 = np.arange(2, 5, 0.1)

xx, yy1 = np.meshgrid(x, y1, sparse=True)
xx, yy2 = np.meshgrid(x, y2, sparse=True)

z1 = np.sin(xx**2 + yy1**2) / (xx**2 + yy1**2)
z2 = xx + yy2

z = np.vstack([z1,z2])
y = np.hstack([y1,y2])
h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

[image]

This doen't work, however, if the regions are divided not by x or y alone but by say x+y.

Comment: Daniel F. and Stef, thanks for your time, I truly appreciate it!. Both solutions work fine. I will implement Daniel's solution because I had something along those lines already.  However, Stef's approach is a great option, since the expression for z = f(x,y) in my application is about 3 lines long, so defining it separately for each region will improve readability and avoid messiness. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you like you can upvote both answers then.

Comment: Stef, certainly I voted for both solutions, but because my 'reputation'... "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I guess, as my 'reputation' improves, hopefully (LOL), then the votes will show. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: OK, no problem (I didn't know that upvoting requires a minimum reputation).